# Python, execute function when some of the list elements have changed

Tags: python, observable

I have the following problem. I have a list of elements of Person type. They have inside them some int members which are constantly changing. When such change occurs, I want to invoke another method. Does anyone can propose some solution to my problem how to invoke the method just after the member is changed?

```
class Person:
    def __init__(self):
        self.age = 20

class Controller:
   p1 = Person()
   p2 = Person()

   personList = [p1,p2]

   def hb:
       print("happy birthday")
```

And I want to invoke hb method when the age of person is changed. The following code is just an example to show the matter.

Comment: Can you add any kind of code, there is tons of ways you can do what you explained and what you expect.

Comment: So, do you want to invoke the method `hb` of `Controller` when the attribute `age` of `p1` or `p2` changes?

Comment: Yes, that what i want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a getter and setter decorator:

```
class MyClass:
    def __init__(self):
        self.init = True
        self.attribute = 1
        self.init = False

    @property
    def attribute(self):
        # Do something if you want
        return self._attribute

    @attribute.setter
    def attribute(self, value):
        if not self.init:
            print('Value of "attribute" changed:', value)
        self._attribute = value

testobject = MyClass()
testobject.attribute = 2
```

I have added an additional init-variable to prevent the changed-code being called in init phase.